# ReactNative state not updating inside function but rendered on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

I'm updating a state in React-Native, changes will be shown on screen but when I call to a function there's my state is not updated.

Here my state will be updated an Rendered to screen.

```
socket.on('event' data => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const newPieces = pieces.map(piece => {
            // Do something and return...
        }
        setPieces(newPieces);
        setDiceNumber(data);
    }, 150);
}
```

This function will be executed after button is clicked.

```
const onPieceTouch = async piece => {
    if (!diceNumber) {
        return;
    }
    // Do Something...
};
```

Inside the onPieceTouch function, diceNumber is 0(InitialState)

I want to update the state perfectly because I faced this problem so many times.
I tried in class component and functional component both, but the problem remains

**Edit --**
Here's the other state variables-

```
const onPieceTouch = async piece => {
    if (!diceNumber || piece.color !== BLUE || disableInput.current || isWaitingForRollDice || turn !== BLUE){
        return;
    }
    // Do Something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making what is called a "stale closure". `diceNumber` is evaluated when the function (closure) is created, and never again, so the value becomes "stale".  There are two main solutions to this issue in React.

1. Rewrite so diceNumber is passed in as an argument to the function.  As long as you make sure whatever calls the function doesn't get stale as well, this will pass in the current value of each.

```js
const onPieceTouch = async (piece, diceNumber) => {
  // ...
```

2. Create the function with useCallback and add diceNumber to its dependency array. useCallback will recreate the function whenever diceNumber changes.

```js
const onPieceTouch = useCallback(async piece => {
  // ...
}, [diceNumber]);
```

Comment: I also have some other values inside the onPieceTouch function. So, why do they get updated as the state updated?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I've updated the question with Edits. Please take a look.